# ContextMenu with footer view (to add checkbox for 'make default' option)

Tags: android, contextmenu

Is there a standard way to add a **footer** to a **context menu**, in which I can add a **checkbox** to make the selected option the default one?
Similar to the context menu that comes up when choosing the default home screen for example.

[image]

From the Api docs for ContextMenu I see that you can set a header view, but not a footer view. Also the `setCheckable` / `setGroupCheckable` methods don't seem to help much here.

Does this need to be done via a custom (alert) dialog? I would be wondering if nobody has yet developed such a component yet in case it's not possible through the standard SDK api. Any standalone open source component out there (beside the Android source itself)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best I've come up with is using an `AlertDialog`

`alert.getListView().addFooterView(...);` and overriding it's `onItemSelected` method.