# footer for custom dialog with a android default theme

Tags: android, android-layout, android-dialog, android-menu

I want to create context menu as follows , i am sure this is not traditional the context menu , its a kind of alert dialog which is being customized.

I tried following code but `it adds the footer end of the ListView not to the dialog / context menu` reference thread is [ContextMenu with footer view (to add checkbox for 'make default' option)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4093640/contextmenu-with-footer-view-to-add-checkbox-for-make-default-option)

```
dialog2.getListView().addFooterView(new CheckBox(this))
```

I have gone through the followig tutorial which has custom context menu , is it possible 
to use this code to set a footer

http://www.tanisoft.net/search/label/Tutorial

I want following features , **preciously the checkbox in the footer**

[image]

**EDIT**

I reached to this part now there are only two issues

> 1) Dialog Title Icon
>   2) Dialog Bottom Blue Color ( which is a default
>   color of android )

and i don;t know how to achieve above two task

Here is my code to create dialog

```
contactDlg = new Dialog(this);
contactDlg.requestWindowFeature( Window.FEATURE_LEFT_ICON );    

contactDlg.setTitle(contactStore.getContactName());

contactDlg.setContentView(R.layout.contact_dialog);
contactDlg.setFeatureDrawableResource(Window.FEATURE_LEFT_ICON, android.R.drawable.bottom_bar);         
contactAdapter = new ContactAdapter(this,contactStore.getContactNumber());          

modeList = (ListView) contactDlg.findViewById(R.id.contactDlgList);
modeList.setBackgroundResource(android.R.color.white);
modeList.setCacheColorHint(Color.WHITE);            
modeList.setAdapter(contactAdapter); 

contactDlg.show();
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

No need to do any thing special for this.
This can be achieved easily by creating your own layout containg the list shown in this pic and the footer view in the dialog itself with thye color and style you want.
Then just make the property of the dialog named "windowFrame" to be null by 
`< item name="android:windowFrame">@null< / item>`
Also you can make a separate "theme.xml" in the "values" folder and define this and similar kinda properties in that file.
In code, when you instantiate the dialog object, set this theme to it.
The basic purpose of doing this is to achieve the total control on what to show and what not in the dialog you create.

Comment: How would i add Footer View ?

Comment: thats what i said in the ans, make the footer view a part of your layout of the dialog.

Comment: you are not providing the layout elements proper hiegth/width/padding/margins.
Thats why it is looking like this.

Comment: I know that sizing is not provided , but what abt the look , can you see the first image which has a default android look

Comment: Well that's obvious that either you need images for background or the color code. Else it won't look gud. So suply your layout with the proper images/color.

Comment: Ya i understand what you are saying but what i am asking is where can i get those colors and all , apart form that as i said before i want to have a default color scheme and images of android , so is that possible

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8097/discussion-between-akkilis-and-hunt)

Comment: come to chat, just click on the link for chat above